# What is the grammar analysis of this (professeur elle aussi)?

Tags: adverbes, ordre-des-mots

> Mon père est professeur...Mon père a une sœur, Marie, ma tante, professeur elle aussi.

I don't understand why did the word "professeur" come before the subject and adverb "aussi".

I try to translate it in English and it's just so weird:

> ... ,teacher she also.

Is this a typical grammar structure with the adverb "aussi"? If so does this have a name?

Comment: it is only because it is nicer when said orally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to write this, all equivalent as to their meaning. I don't think there is anything special about the adverb.

- Mon père est professeur...Mon père a une sœur, Marie, ma tante, professeur elle aussi.
- Mon père est professeur...Mon père a une sœur, Marie, ma tante,  elle aussi professeur.
- Mon père est professeur...Mon père a une sœur, Marie, ma tante,  elle aussi est professeur.
- Mon père est professeur...Mon père a une sœur, Marie, ma tante, qui est elle aussi professeur.
- Mon père est professeur...Mon père a une sœur, Marie, ma tante, qui  elle aussi est professeur.
- Mon père est professeur...Mon père a une sœur, Marie, ma tante, qui    est professeur elle aussi.

The short forms can be considered to be ellipted forms obtained from a longer one.  In the third case the two clauses are connected without coordination word, just a comma (parataxis).

- Pierre est souvent malade… Pierre a un ami, Paul, de même souvent malade.
- Pierre est souvent malade… Pierre a un ami, Paul, souvent malade, de même.

Comment: Pouvons nous utiliser aussi : Mon père est professeur...Mon père a une sœur, Marie, ma tante, **dont** le metier est professeur aussi

Comment: @SkyLand77 C'est une option qui est tout aussi valable.

Answer (score 5):

Word by word translation can be helpful but rarely gives a proper sentence.

Here is a rare case where English uses an article while French doesn't.

Another point,  ***aussi***, being after the noun better translates to ***too*** or ***as well*** instead of ***also***

A better translation of "*professeur elle aussi*" is then:

> a teacher too.

Like in English, we can reverse the order of the words that way:

> *elle aussi professeur*: also a teacher

The pronoun ***elle*** is optional in the first form and is clarifying or emphasizing who this is about. It is not a subject pronoun but a tonic one so would translate to "**her**", not "**she**" so the the literal translation to English would be more like:

> *Mon père est professeur...Mon père a une sœur, Marie, ma tante, professeur elle aussi.*

> My father is a teacher... My father has a sister, Marie, my aunt, a teacher (her) too.

Here ***elle aussi*** is built like

- *moi aussi* (me too)
- *toi/vous aussi* (you too)
- *lui aussi* (him too)
- *nous aussi* (us too)
- *eux aussi/elles aussi* (them too).

I guess "my aunt, also a teacher" would be the most common way to say it in English.